# How do I call another controller action from within a controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a `node` which can be of different types (a `Comment` & `Video`).

What I want to happen is whenever I delete a `node`, it should also delete the underlying object it points to - e.g. a `Video`.

Here are my models (truncated where necessary for brevity):

`Node.rb`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: nodes
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  name           :string(255)
#  family_tree_id :integer
#  user_id        :integer
#  media_id       :integer
#  media_type     :string(255)
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#  circa          :datetime
#  is_comment     :boolean
#

class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :node_comments, dependent: :destroy

  def is_video?
    self.media_type == 'Video'
  end

  def comment_count
    self.node_comments.count + self.comments.count
  end
end
```

Here is my `Video.rb`:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: videos
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  title       :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  yt_video_id :string(255)
#  is_complete :boolean
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#  reply_id    :integer
#  circa       :datetime
#

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :description, :yt_video_id, :is_complete, :user_ids

  has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :participants
  has_one :node, as: :media, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :node, update_only: true

  def self.yt_session
    @yt_session ||= YouTubeIt::Client.new(:username => YouTubeITConfig.username , :password => YouTubeITConfig.password , :dev_key => YouTubeITConfig.dev_key)
  end

  def self.delete_video(video)
    yt_session.video_delete(video.yt_video_id)
    video.destroy
      rescue
        video.destroy
  end
end
```

`Comment.rb`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: comments
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  message    :text
#  node_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :message, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :node

  def self.search(query)
    where("title like ? OR description like ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  end
end
```

`NodeController#Destroy`

```
  def destroy
    @node.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

`VideoController#Destroy`

```
  def destroy
    authorize! :read, @family_tree
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    if Video.delete_video(@video)
      flash[:notice] = "video successfully deleted"
    else
      flash[:error] = "video unsuccessfully deleted"
    end
    redirect_to dashboard_index_path
  end
```

`CommentController#Destroy`

```
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

So all I want to do is whenever there is a node deleted, I want it to delete the associated video & comment.

I tried adding this to my `Node.rb` model, but when I hit delete it returned a "stack level too deep error":

```
belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to take `dependent: :destroy` out of
`has_one :node, as: :media, :dependent => :destroy` in video.rb. Then you shouldn't get infinite recursion when you use this line in node.rb:
`belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Hrmm...interesting. I still want to figure out how to delete the related objects. Thoughts?